# CSS style=display:block not working

Tags: html, css

Browser is Firefox.

I have a list of 15 radio buttons. After displaying them like this:

```
<div class="abcd"  style="margin-left:10px;">
    <form id='some'....>
        <legend>Select Item type :</legend>
        <fieldset style="display:block;float:left;">
            <input class="yy" id="sss" type="radio" name="group0" value="aaa"/> ABC
            ...
        </fieldset>
        <p>
            <input placeholder="Enter Name/Value" name="xxx" id="xxx" size="40" style="display:block;float:left;">
            <button type="button" id="xxx" style="width:100;">Process</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Everything is displaying in one line. I am not sure how to display the textbox under radio buttons with some space in between.?

pl help.

Comment: you should be using the `<label>` tag around your labels (like ABC)

Comment: why would you set an `<input>` element to `display:block`?

Comment: how to add <label> around ABC? Also in input i used block because i was trying to display it in next line.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem with your style is the `float: left`, you have to clear the "floatness".
At the `p` tag, include the `clear:both`, it tells the browser that nothing can float at its left or right.

```
<div class="abcd"  style="margin-left:10px;">
    <form id='some'>
        <fieldset style="display:block;float:left;">
            <input class="yy" id="sss" type="radio" name="group0" value="aaa"/> ABC

            <input class="yy" id="sss" type="radio" name="group0" value="aaa"/> ABC

            <input class="yy" id="sss" type="radio" name="group0" value="aaa"/> ABC

        </fieldset>
        <p style="clear:both">
            <input placeholder="Enter Name/Value" name="xxx" id="xxx" size="40" style="display:block;float:left;">
            <button type="button" id="xxx" style="width:100;">Process</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the `float` attribute you have to clear it so that other elements won't appear floating next to it. try adding `clear: both` to the css of the input box like this:

```
<input placeholder="Enter Name/Value" name="Name" id="NameID" size="40" 
style="clear:both; display:block;"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

paste

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

after the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the css rule to the radio buttons themselves. Like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.group0
{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

This assumes `group0` is the group with all the radio buttons.